# someone is using may sendmail to spam other

Tags: security, sendmail

I have an Ubuntu  (14.04.1 LTS) install on AWS with *sendmail*.

I keep getting messages from mail servers that are unable to deliver some of my messages (I did not send) and all are about sex.

So I figure someone is using my server to spam people.

How do I start handling this?

Can anyone direct me to article or tutorial explaining this?

Answer (score 0):

If sendmail is sending out those messages, you should check the logs. Bit cheap of me, but please start at the link be below. Combine the email addresses, time stamps mentioned in the NDR's (Non-Delivery Report) and check the logs.

[where-to-check-log-of-sendmail](https://serverfault.com/questions/59602/where-to-check-log-of-sendmail)

But, you might not be even sending those emails from your server.

It could be bounce back/[backscatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_%28email%29), some other server sending spam --but using your domainname as the sender. When the receiving server can't (or won't) deliver them it returns a NDR to your server with the help of the DNS MX records.

You might be able to see if this is the case if you look at the headers & messages of the NDR reports you receive.

What might help (...but not 100% of the time...) in these cases is making it harder for spammers to abuse your domainname. With the help of SPF & DKIM records.

See: [bounce-back-backscatter-spam-who-stole-my-email-address](https://luxsci.com/blog/bounce-back-backscatter-spam-who-stole-my-email-address.html)

Comment: Thanks for this
Checking the log, looks like someone is sending those email from the server:
I get lots of log records all saying from=<some_name@my_domain_name> (the right names here…)
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you see the ip address from where the connection came from? Does this belong to the user in question? (alteast the correct region?) If not, consider checking with the user if his/her password might have been "guessed" and someone is sending email mail through your server smtp services. Any other services running on the server that could be being exploited, for instance, www (wordpress)?

Comment: Thanks for your replay, 
I am including a small part of the log here 
I have no users as such, I keep web sites on this server and I have Drupal installed

Comment: Here is the extract:

Comment: Apr  5 06:29:50 ip-172-30-0-66 postfix/smtp[13750]: connect to mx5.o2.pl[193.17.41.45]:25: Connection timed out
Apr  5 06:29:50 ip-172-30-0-66 postfix/smtp[13765]: C19C5691E6: to=<jozef6@o2.pl>, relay=none, delay=69208, delays=69058/0/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx3.o2.pl[193.17.41.214]:25: Connection timed out)
Apr  5 06:29:50 ip-172-30-0-66 postfix/smtp[13750]: C07CA698B9: to=<majpiotr161@o2.pl>, relay=none, delay=65047, delays=64897/0/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect

Comment: Be sure to check the folder of your drupal site, use the modification date as a guideline if you haven't changed/updated in a while. Check for files that shouldn't be there. Also check your apache(nginx) logs to see if you see any strange repeating "POST" requests to files you can't place. If you do spot any, check out these also files. Your site might been compromised and they are using a php-mailer to send spam. You will receive the NDR's then also.

Comment: If you are running an older version of drupal, please also make sure you haven't become the victim of this exploit. https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005

It's possible the code they placed is hiding somewhere in your (my)sql database. 

I'm being very specific here with the exploit, but in general, be sure to keep your drupal updated. It could be this or any other being exploited.